# Why my toString() does not work in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

i have a code below where i try to create a Alarm clock. I have problem with string and toString. Which is shown as red in Android Studio. I have tried String.valueOf(value) but it have same problem with string??

any suggestions?

```
    public String AlarmTime() {
        int alarmHours = alarmTime.getCurrentHour();
        int alarmMinutes = alarmTime.getCurrentMinute();
        String stringAlarmMinutes;

        if (alarmMinutes < 10) {
            stringAlarmMinutes = "0";
            stringAlarmMinutes = stringAlarmMinutes.concat(alarmMinutes.toString());
        } else {
            stringAlarmMinutes = alarmMinutes.toString();
        }

        String stringAlarmTime;

        if(alarmHours > 12) {
            alarmHours=alarmHours - 12;
            stringAlarmTime=alarmHours.toString().concat(":").concat(alarmMinutes.toString()).concat(" PM");
        } else {
            stringAlarmTime=alarmHours.toString().concat(":").concat(alarmMinutes.toString()).concat(" AM");
        }
        return stringAlarmTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: "it have same problem with string" - What does this mean? Do you get an exception/error in the IDE? What exactly?

Comment: I presume that you are referring to the compilation errors you will get for this: `alarmMinutes.toString();`.   You are attempting to invoke an "instance" method on a primitive type (`int`).  You can't do that in Java.  Use `Integer.toString(int)` to convert the `int` to a `String`.

Comment: P.S. This is a Java programming problem, not a problem with Android Studio.

Comment: P.P.S - Use the `+` operator to concatenate Java strings; e.g. `Integer.toString(alarmHours) + ":" + Integer.toString(alarmMinutes) + " AM"`.  Or better still `String.format("%d:%d AM", alarmHours, alarmMinutes)`

Comment: i have tried all of your suggested to me...but there is still problem with String word...i dont understand why

Comment: I don't know what you are saying.  What "problem with String word" are you talking about?

Comment: You haven't done something crazy ... like defining a class of your own called `String`?

Comment: Nope, i have followed tutorial and he does exact same stuff and toString worked for him...

Comment: There is also problems "Unexpected implicit cast to `TextClock`: layout tag was `TextView`"

Comment: here is a website https://programmerworld.co/android/create-a-simple-alarm-clock-app-in-android-studio/

Comment: re *he does exact same stuff* - no, he doesn't.   You wrote `int`.  He wrote `Integer`.  One's a primitive type, the other is an object.  They are not freely interchangeable.

Comment: I have changed Int to Integer ant it turn into red color too. Sorry, i am really new into this but i really work for solution.

Comment: Bro, this was the issue !! Integer is nor integer and now toString stuff works... thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types such as `int` do not have any methods, let alone a `toString` method.

`String.valueOf(int)` should be ok, so you must have made some other error there. I can't say, since you did not post that version.

Comment: This is from console

Comment: C:\Users\svice\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAlarm\app\src\main\java\com\blueadmin\myalarm\MainActivity.java:32: error: method equals in class String cannot be applied to given types;
                if (currentTime.getText().toString().equals()){
                                                    ^
  required: Object
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: and String.valueOf(int) dont work with String again....

Comment: Error messages often will actually tell you what's wrong, if you read them.  There is no `equals()` that takes 0 arguments. Think about it - equal to **what**?   And what has that to do with `String.valueOf(int)` anyway, which is what we were discussing.